# Laravel queue with custom SQS Data

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sqs

Is there a way to use Laravel's queue worker to process custom messages from an AWS SQS queue?

---

I have a custom queue within Amazon SQS I want to process messages from. I see Laravel has a queue listener that really does all this for you, BUT I can't find any documentation on how to build custom listeners/deserializer.

When using `queue:work` on the queue, Laravel is throwing an exception:

```
[2020-05-13 22:02:00] local.ERROR: Undefined index: job {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: job at /Users/pz/Documents/Envision/source/services/case-search/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:288, ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: job at /Users/pz/Documents/Envision/source/services/case-search/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:200)
```

The reason is because it's looking for a `job` index at the root of the payload. The messages does not have any such index. I need some way to catch this to run my own handler.

Example data:

```
(
  'Type' => 'Notification',
  'MessageId' => '47cffb48-3811-5c7e-af60-5d6e51ac7e48',
  'TopicArn' => 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:topic',
  'Subject' => 'cud-event.table',
  'Message' => '{
  "table": "myTable",
  "action": "insert",
  "ts": 1589407243.8653,
  "data_new": {
   /// [...message data...]
  }
}',
  'Timestamp' => '2020-05-13T22:00:44.083Z',
  'SignatureVersion' => '1',
  // [... AWS sigs ...]
)
```

Ideally, it would be perfect if we can tell Laravel to look for "Message.table" object, e.g. `myTable`, or simply a noramlized "Subject" object.

Comment: The response in this thread helped me a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870928/how-to-intercept-a-new-file-on-s3-using-laravel-queues  You can also look at this package: https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-plain-sqs